# How to setup node-gyp behide a proxy

Tags: karma-runner, node-gyp

When i install karma that use node-gyp to fetch package and do rebuild, and I got a "gyp Error!: connect ECONNERFUSED", THE problem whey node-gyp will connect to internet and my environment is behind corporate proxy, I could download package from npm and I setup npm's proxy already.

My environment is WINDOWS 7 64 bit.

I found no where to setting node-gyp in proxy. any idea for that?

[Update] Thanks. I got how to setup this, command as below
    node-gyp configure --proxy=http://proxy.address.com:port

[image: node-gyp connect ECONNERFUSED]

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Hi @HossamBarakat, yes,  command as below node-gyp configure --proxy=http://proxy.address.com:port

Comment: Dint work for me I get gyp ERR! stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown pro

Comment: I am behind a company firewall that uses ssl CA Certs anyone know how to add that to node-gyp?

Answer (score 5):

I am stuck behind a corporate firewall. The only solution I could find was to override the default SSL CA files with the company provided ones.

Solution using company ssl CA files:
`node-gyp configure --cafile="/path/to/mycafile.pem"`

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this error recently.  I believe the fix that finally solved it for me was adding an environment variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`.  The value should be the same full path to a PEM-formatted certificate bundle for your proxy's root cert, similar to Tim's answer.  The advantage is that it should work for any Node package that tries to make SSL connections.

Answer (score 0):

Setting npm `proxy` works for **node-gyp** and **node-pre-gyp** "fallback to build" installation. Even http proxy server works for https sites like github.com. Below command adds a new line `proxy=http://localhost:7788` into your `$HOME/.npmrc`:

```
npm config set proxy http://localhost:7788
```